# CSS font-size changes when font-family falls back

Tags: css

I want to use a font (gill sans) which renders very small due to a short x-height etc. etc. If I set this at a reasonable size, and then a browser falls back to a more typical font I've specified in the font-family, the fall-back font renders very large - can I set the font-size according to the font the browser is using?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue using Calibri (slightly smaller compared to most sans fonts).  I ended up doing the following (assumes you have jquery):

1. Get Remy Sharp's font detection script http://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/
2. Add the following to the `$(document).ready()` function:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       font.setup();
       if(!font.isInstalled('Calibri'))
           $('body').css('font-size','87.5%');
   });
   ```

So now if the user doesn't have Calibri we see Arial at 87.5%.  This only applied to elements where font-size was not defined/inherited.  Wherever font-size is explicitly defined will have to be adjusted as well (maybe add a class to those elements and change the jquery selector to `$('.adjustClass'))`.

Would be nice if you could just do:
`font:11px Calibri, 10px Arial;` - but no such luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you try and specify cascading fonts that degrade gracefully when fonts are not available e.g.

```
Arial, FontThatsLikeArial, FontThatsALittleLikeArial, FontThatsALittleLessLikeArial, Sans-serif;
```

Alternatively if you want tight control over your fonts, take a look a cufon, that doesn't require your users have any plug-ins and works on most modern browsers. https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/about

Answer (score 1):

There was an interesting article written a few weeks ago that addresses this topic.

You can read the article here: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2009/css-xhtml/combining-cufon-and-font-face/

In short, the article is utilizing a few methods... @font-face for modernized browsers, a jQuery font detection script, and Cufon for font replacement if prior methods fail.

This is not a perfect solution. And like many above me stated, your best bet is to use a font that degrades gracefully.

Try setting your font-stacks to something like 
'GillSans, Calibri, Trebuchet, sans-serif' - for paragraph copy, or
'GillSans, Trebuchet, Calibri, sans-serif' - for titles and headings

Answer (score 0):

> can I set the font-size according to the font the browser is using?

Unfortunately, no, not in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using typical Fonts that are found on most (/all) machines that access the website you are building. The view of a website shouldn't differ because of the browser (IE-related problems is another topic...).
Use common fonts or alternatives that do work similar...

Answer (score -1):

You can specify a font-size in the body selector and thus neutralize the browser's default size, i.e.

```
body { font-size: 62.5%; }
```

62.5% is a good baseline because it allows you to easily use ems to relatively set the font-size of elements in the body.

At 62.5%, 1em = 10px, 1.2em = 12px and so on.

Just set a font-size in the body as baseline and style elements accordingly.

Comment: The relation between % of font size and px depends on the users default font size, and on dpi.

Comment: please don't do this.  some of us actually change our browser settings to have a base font size we like.  with this rule in place, your entire website will be unreadably tiny.