# Dynamic Font Scaling CSS

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

I love using the MS fonts for Vista, they're great. However they're several points smaller than the common failsafe fonts, meaning a website optimized for the Vista fonts won't look nice for people with older fonts.

The problem is described in this old article:

http://neosmart.net/blog/2006/css-vistas-new-fonts/

It's been 3 years since. Has any solution been found? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of

1. [Changing Body Font-Size based on Font-Family with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271477/changing-body-font-size-based-on-font-family-with-jquery)
2. [CSS font-size changes when font-family falls back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829933/css-font-size-changes-when-font-family-falls-back)