# Change font-size according to font-family using CSS?

Tags: css, font-size

I have this in my CSS:

```
font-family: "Microsoft Yi Baiti","Verdana";
font-size: 22px;
```

The 22px are ok for the Microsoft font, but not for Verdana. If the Microsoft font is not installed it will switch to Verdana, thats ok. The font size for Verdana must be 15px however. How can I say that as soon as the alternative is chosen (Verdana), a font-sie of 15px should be used?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS font-size changes when font-family falls back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829933/css-font-size-changes-when-font-family-falls-back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need some javascript to resolve this problem, in my opinion.

1. You should take a look to this link http://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/
2. Create a little script for each of your fonts

If the font **Microsoft Yi Baiti** is not installed you will put the font size of the second font to 15px. You can also create a test for each fonts, and add the font-size value for each.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  font.setup(); // run setup when the DOM is ready  

  if(!font.isInstalled('Microsoft Yi Baiti')) {  
   $('body').css('font-size','15px');  
  }  
});
```